# How to make child div occupy full space of parent's div in a resizable bootstrap panel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I have a resizable bootstrap panel (using the jQuery UI resizable plugin); I am trying to have a `<div>` within the `panel-body` div, that would occupy all space, eg. to have this div occupying the panel body full space as it is resized.

I thought it would be enough to define some CSS rules, like setting `height: 100%;` and
`width: 100%` but it doesn't work (why ? I am new to CSS and sadly I can't understand why it fails). I ended up using `alsoResize` to make sure my `div` is resized at the same time as its parent, but it doesn't give satisfactory results.

I tried other magic without success ; I don't like magic, anyway ;)

For my tests I put the background color to be yellow ; surprisingly, before the first resize the `<div>` doesn't even show up !

Any help and a bit of explanations would be appreciated.

**CSS:**

```
.dashboard_panel {
    min-height: 200px;
}
.panel-body {
    min-height:200px;
    height:100%;
}
.mydiv {
    background-color:yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-info dashboard_panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">id23/emotion/m0</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="mydiv"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".dashboard_panel").resizable({
    alsoResize: ".mydiv, .panel-body"
});
```

And a [link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mguijarr/6vqrkwn2/)

Comment: `.dashboard_panel { min-height: 200px; }` missing a `.` before.

Comment: A good way to debug this would be to add a different colored 1px border to each div and see where they are in relation to each other.

Comment: @Nicolas Copy & Paste error; it's there in the Fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but adding this might help:

```
.panel-body {
    position: relative;
    min-height:200px;
    height:100%;
}

.mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    background-color:yellow;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vqrkwn2/3/)

Comment: Yes! It's exactly what I was after. Can you explain more in the details what `position: relative` or `absolute` is doing? It is totally obscure to me!

Comment: when adding some margins (top:10px, bottom:10px, left:10px, right:10px), when making it very small, then bigger it doesn't resize properly again; any idea why?

Comment: "position: absolute" and setting the top, bottom, left, and right on the child div sets the boundaries of .mydiv to those same boundaries of the first "postion: relative" parent it encounters, or that is my understanding. The resizing issue probably has something to do with the resize plugin being attached to so many nested divs.

Answer (score 1):

Your `row-fluid` and `col-md-12` are adding padding (15px each for a total of 30px on left and right).

Change `row-fluid` to `row` and remove the `col-md-12`.  The panel will automatically take up the full width on all screen sizes.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-info dashboard_panel">
            <div class="panel-heading">id23/emotion/m0</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="mydiv"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vqrkwn2/2/)

Comment: The problem is that the div within panel-body (with class 'mydiv') doesn't occupy all its parent space. The code in the question is a largely stripped down version of something more elaborated, in fact I need the 12 columns padding is not a problem for me.

Comment: Ok so maybe the other answer is what you're looking for.